# VB.NET Strings.Chr to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

How to convert :

```
strMenu.Append("        <ul>" + Strings.Chr(13));
```

to C#?

Comment: @user257234 maybe it's VB# :)

Comment: If you just want to convert 13 to it's character value then casting as char via `(char)13` will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
strMenu += "        <ul>\r";
```

Is the direct translation. It is possible you would like to use this instead:

```
strMenu += "        <ul>" + Enviroment.NewLine;
```

Since NewLine is the new line sequence for the current runtime environment.

Comment: @DOK, not really. This is probably not HTML.

Comment: -1. Neither is correct. \n is Chr(10), not Chr(13). `Environment.NewLine` depends on the platform.

Answer (score 6):

These are the C# equivalents:

```
strMenu.Append("        <ul>\r");

strMenu.Append("        <ul>\u000d");

strMenu.Append("        <ul>" + (char)13);
```